# Facing Lint error (Expected 2 arguments, but got 1) while testing window.scrollBy() method in Jasmine after Angular Upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

While doing the upgrade to Angular 11, a couple of other packages like jasmine-core has also been upgraded. Due to which while running the 'npm run test' command causing various lint issue as they have made the 'types' more strict.

One of the issues is with window.scrollBy() method. As per the type definition file (lib.dom.ts), it can have 2 overloaded implementations like below -

```
scrollBy(options?: ScrollToOptions): void;
scrollBy(x: number, y: number): void;
```

But while writing the unit test case, it is giving Lint error as below -

```js
it('should scroll down by 10 units', fakeAsync(() => {
    service.scrollDown(10);
    expect(window.scrollBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      top: 10,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }));
```

[image]

It looks like it is considering only the second overloaded implementation, not the first one where we can also pass only parameter i.e. "options". Although the test case is getting passed correctly.

I have created a minimal reproduction example on below Github link. Please let me know in-case any additional information required. Any help or pointers would be really appreciated.

https://github.com/HimanshuGoel/scrollByIssue

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Not yet. I am using just toHaveBeenCalled() instead of toHaveBeenCalledWith() as a workaround for now. :(

Comment: Same issue with the `scrollTo` function. The only thing that fixed the issue was adding `// @ts-ignore`, but this is not a good solution. By the way, it's not a lint issue, it's a TypeScript compile error.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the `scrollBy()` function is overloaded, among other scroll functions like `scrollTo()`. The `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` function has a know issue with the typing of overloaded functions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/42455

To make the compiler happy, you can check the arguments of the first call directly, using `any`:

```
it('should scroll down by 10 units', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(window, 'scrollBy');
    service.scrollDown(10);
    expect(spy.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual([{
      top: 10,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    } as any]);
  }));
```

However there might be cases where this doesn't work, i.e. when there are multiple calls to the spy function and you don't know in advance which is the right one. I had one case like this, and it's the first time in 5 years of using TypeScript that I have put a `// @ts-ignore` to my code.